# warning LNK4254: section 'ATL' (50000040) merged into '.rdata' (40000040) with different attributes

Tags: c++, linker, warnings, atl

I am receiving this warning many times for my project:

```
warning LNK4254: section 'ATL' (50000040) merged into '.rdata' (40000040) with different attributes
```

I am compiling using Visual Studio 2010 Professional Edition, the 2010 version of the compiler, but VC++ **2005** libraries.

This seems to be the cause. If I use the 2010 libraries, or the 2005 compiler, the problem disappears with no changes to the code. However, I want to use the 2005 libraries and 2010 compiler together if I possibly can.

Does anybody know how to fix this, or whether these warnings are definitely safe to ignore/disable?

Thank you.

EDIT: The problem seems to be caused by a change in atlbase.h:

2005:

```
#if defined(_M_IA64) || defined(_M_IX86) || defined (_M_AMD64)

#pragma section("ATL$__a", read, shared)
#pragma section("ATL$__z", read, shared)
#pragma section("ATL$__m", read, shared)
extern "C"
{
__declspec(selectany) __declspec(allocate("ATL$__a")) _ATL_OBJMAP_ENTRY* __pobjMapEntryFirst = NULL;
__declspec(selectany) __declspec(allocate("ATL$__z")) _ATL_OBJMAP_ENTRY* __pobjMapEntryLast = NULL;
}

#if !defined(_M_IA64)
#pragma comment(linker, "/merge:ATL=.rdata")
#endif

#else

extern "C"
{
__declspec(selectany) _ATL_OBJMAP_ENTRY* __pobjMapEntryFirst = NULL;
__declspec(selectany) _ATL_OBJMAP_ENTRY* __pobjMapEntryLast = NULL;
}

#endif  // defined(_M_IA64) || defined(_M_IX86)
```

2010:

```
#pragma section("ATL$__a", read)
#pragma section("ATL$__z", read)
#pragma section("ATL$__m", read)
extern "C"
{
__declspec(selectany) __declspec(allocate("ATL$__a")) _ATL_OBJMAP_ENTRY* __pobjMapEntryFirst = NULL;
__declspec(selectany) __declspec(allocate("ATL$__z")) _ATL_OBJMAP_ENTRY* __pobjMapEntryLast = NULL;
}

#if !defined(_M_IA64)
#pragma comment(linker, "/merge:ATL=.rdata")
#endif
```

But I don't see how to use this knowledge to fix my problem :(

Comment: There is a project option to choose the platform toolset, but unfortunately I believe you can only backup to the 2008 toolset. Is there a reason you need to use the old VS2005 libraries. The VC redistributables support side by side installation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I manually modified the MSBuild Platform Toolset files in order to go back that far. This program must be able to operate on a Windows Vista install where I cannot install any VC++ Redistributables. I have to go back far enough that Vista SP0 comes with them out of the box. VC++ 2005 is the latest version this is true for AFAIK.

Comment: Another way around that would be to put the redistributable dlls in your exe folder on install OR you could statically link, but IMHO dropping the dlls on install into the same folder is a better option.

Comment: Are you trying to use ATL libraries with VS 2010 Express, and ATL comes from WDK? I suppose you would have to patch ATL libs to have matching section flags (AFAIR this is required for being DEP compliant) See also http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromium.git;a=commitdiff;h=b9e35854b4d2d7361b618d265ba8919013d285fb and http://atlserver.codeplex.com/workitem/12158

Comment: Thank you both again. I am not actually using the Express Edition, but Professional. Does this make a difference? @RomanR., one of the posts in that second thread you linked me to (thank you :) ) suggested modifying the header files themselves. I am a little reluctant to do this, but if it is the best fix, then that is great. Would it be better to fix it in this way (not merge the sections), or ignore this warning? Thanks again.

Comment: @niemiro: if you are using Pro version, you have a fresher ATL version available with the Visual Studio itself. Old ATL might make sense for Express Edition shipped without ATL. It is hard to tell whether it is safe to ignore the warning, I would try it on DEP-enabled system and check its operation. If it is good, then maybe you can ignore it.

Comment: Thanks again. I have now resolved this problem. I recoded all parts of the application using ATL not to use ATL :p It was only a few tiny areas of the application anyway, and didn't take very long. Was that the solution you were expecting!?

Comment: @niemiro: "Was that the solution you were expecting?" Yes and no. To not use ATL 2005? Yes. To not use ATL 2010? No.